# how to avoid using a empty method implementation?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a question regarding the structures of my classes in java :

I have a first class : MyClass that is abstract

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    protected void abstract monitor();
}
```

then I have an abstract iterator on it

```
public abstract class MyClassIterator<T> extends MyClass
{
    protected void abstract monitor(T data);
}
```

In practice I will after create classes that will either inherit from MyClass or MyClassIterator.

I want to make sure all instances of MyClass implement monitor but for the iterator ones, how can I avoid inserting something like

```
protected void monitor() {};
```

just to implement it :/

Thanks for any idea :)

Comment: Does `MyClassIterator` **have** to extend `MyClass`?

Comment: Thats not in your control. Implementing class can have any implementation or blank code block like you said `protected void monitor() {};`

Comment: @Mena : that's a good question, currently that's what has been done as MyClass is defining methods that will be also used in the iterator, so we would need to duplicate the code otherwise :S

Comment: thats why someone should throw and  UnsupportedOperationException there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want that `MyClassIterator` subclasses will have to implement this method, then you have to add the empty implementation to `MyClassIterator`.
You can also throw some exception in the implementation.

```
public abstract class MyClassIterator<T> extends MyClass
{
    protected abstract void monitor(T data);

    protected void monitor() {
        //optional
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Note: You can't write `void` before `abstract`, you need to fix this in your `monitor(T data)` method, like in my answer.

Comment: Indeed it's ok like that, not super nice but fixes all the issues :)

Comment: If you use ` throw new UnsupportedOperationException()`, wouldn't the IDE still suggest (or auto-add) call to the `super.monitor()`, causing crash from this exception?

Answer (score 3):

Add a default implementation of `monitor` in `MyClass`, with a customized exception

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    protected void abstract monitor()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thereby, `MyClassIterator` won't have to implement the method and other subclasses of `MyClass` will have to override it.